# Pandas Dataframe: Can I fetch other column values along with the column on which group by clause has been applied?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this data set which contains price for items sold across various stores on a week wise basis.

The dataframe: price_df looks like this:

```
price_df.head()
   store_id      item_id week    sell_price
0      S1         item1    w1          9.58
1      S1         item1    w2          9.00
2      S2         item1    w1          8.30
3      S2         item1    w2          8.50
4      S2         item2    w1          8.26
```

I want to find out : for each 'item and store' combination the highest price

My code:

```
item_store_max_prices = price_df.groupby(["store_id","item_id"]).agg({"sell_price":["max"]})
```

But this would only show the store_id, item_id and for that combination the max price ever listed.

Problem statement:

However, I want to show the week as well on which that max price has been observed for that 'store - item' combination in my resultset.

For example:

```
    store_id     item_id  week    sell_price
0      S1         item1    w1          9.58
1      S2         item1    w2          8.50
```

Could you please help me with how to obtain that result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find indexes of the rows having the `max` values using [`df.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html).

Then subset the dataframe using the above indices using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), like this:

```
idx = price_df.groupby(["store_id","item_id"])['sell_price'].idxmax().tolist()
price_df = price_df.loc[idx]
```

**Output:**

```
  store_id item_id week  sell_price
0       S1   item1   w1        9.58
3       S2   item1   w2        8.50
4       S2   item2   w1        8.26
```